# new Neo4j install: "No authorization header supplied" even after editing config file

Tags: neo4j

I just installed Neo4j today to play around on my Ubuntu EC2 instance, and I'm having two problems. First, the ubuntu install did not create a neo4j command so I'm not able to issue commands from the cli. Second, when I try this sample command to add a node to the database, I get the error

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher -d '{
  "query" : "CREATE (n:Person { name : {name} }) RETURN n",
  "params" : {
    "name" : "Foo"
  }
}'
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied.",
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
  } ]
```

I read the docs here, and I modified the config file per these instructions:
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html

I updated the config file so that it should not require authentication:

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

But still my curl requests to my localhost Neo4j server are blocked. All I can think is maybe neo4j needs a restart, but since I have no neo4j command, I can't use `neo4j restart`. I logged into the neo4j shell, but in the shell's list of commands there is no restart.

So my questions are:

(1) How can I restart neo4j?

(2) Where is my neo4j command/how can I create one following a standard ubuntu install?

(3) How could I create a username/password if I wanted to keep the access authentication in place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You restart Neo4j by calling `/path/to/neo/bin/neo4j restart` 
or by  `/etc/init.d/neo4j restart` if you installed it as a service.

The neo4j startup script is in the same path as the shell.

Answer (score -2):

You can restart the Neo4J service using:

```
sudo service neo4j-service restart
```

from the shell.